# Plot a black-and-white binary map in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using python to simulate some automation models, and with the help of matplotlib I'm producing plots like the one shown below.

[image]

I'm currently plotting with the following command:

```
ax.imshow(self.g, cmap=map, interpolation='nearest')
```

where `self.g` is the binary map (`0` -> blue, `1` -> red in my current plots).

However, to include this in my report I would like the plot to be with black dots on white background instead of red on blue. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can change the color map you are using via the `cmap` keyword. The color map `'Greys'` provides the effect you want. You can find a list of [available maps on the scipy website](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Show_colormaps.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(101)
g = np.floor(np.random.random((100, 100)) + .5)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.imshow(g)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.imshow(g, cmap='Greys',  interpolation='nearest')
plt.savefig('blkwht.png')

plt.show()
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: You can just give the name of the colormap to `cmap`. `plt.imshow(g, cmap="Greys")` would do the same thing.

Comment: you may also use plt.gray() at the beginning to get similar results.

Comment: In my version of matplotlib (1.5.2rc2) I had to use cmap='gray' . Guess they changed the names a bit. If you do it wrong though, it prints out all the options, which is nice.

Answer (score 18):

There is an alternative method to Yann's answer that gives you finer control. Matplotlib's [imshow](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) can take a `MxNx3` matrix where each entry is the RGB color value - just set them to white `[1,1,1]` or black `[0,0,0]` accordingly. If you want three colors it's easy to expand this method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Z is your data set
N = 100
Z = np.random.random((N,N))

# G is a NxNx3 matrix
G = np.zeros((N,N,3))

# Where we set the RGB for each pixel
G[Z>0.5] = [1,1,1]
G[Z<0.5] = [0,0,0]

plt.imshow(G,interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]