# matplotlib: binary heat plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

Let's say I have a 10x10 matrix, that is comprised or just 0s and 1s, represented as a list of lists. How could I use `matplotlib` to represent such a matrix as a grid of red and black squares? (red for 1, black for 0).

I've search extensively, but the closest I could find was [`Plot a black-and-white binary map in matplotlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638826/plot-a-black-and-white-binary-map-in-matplotlib), but the colors are floats less than 1. Once I get 1s in the data, the plot goes awry. Can anyone help? Or point to specific matplotlib documentation that would help me overcome this?

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707676/defining-a-discrete-colormap-for-imshow-in-matplotlib/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need what's known as a `ListedColorMap`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# random data
x = np.random.random_integers(0, 1, (10, 10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# define the colors
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['r', 'k'])

# create a normalize object the describes the limits of
# each color
bounds = [0., 0.5, 1.]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# plot it
ax.imshow(x, interpolation='none', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
```

[image]

Comment: There's also [`from_levels_and_colors`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.from_levels_and_colors)if you want a function that generates the colormap and norm in one shot.  E.g. `cmap, norm = from_levels_and_colors([0, 0.5, 1], ['r', 'k'])`

Comment: @tcaswell - It was added fairly recently (~1.2, I think?).  Oddly enough, I thought you were the one who added it, but it looks like it was Phil: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/c16c3c290eb32c4e8874a0e9cf4946a2b57b5dc3

Comment: This works, but the colours were reversed: 1 was black, and 0 was red. I changed the colours in the `cmap` line: 
`cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['k', 'r'])` and now it works!