# Coloring Matplotlib heatmap according to requirement

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I created a simple matplotlib heatmap where every cell will be red or green if the value of the cell is higher than `2.3`.

Now, instead of having the color simply red or green, i would like to have it
darker or lighter according to how much does the value of the cell differs from `2.3`, for example `1` will have a darker red than `2.1`.

Is there any way to do this? Until now, i only managed to do it binary, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517400/matplotlib-binary-heat-plot).

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

a = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9],
              [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0],
              [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3],
              [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0],
              [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6]])

cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['#ff3d3d', '#74ff52'])

bounds = [np.amin(a), 2.3, np.amax(a)]

norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

ax1.imshow(a, interpolation='none', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html) can create a continuous colormap from a list of colors. It helps to explicitly set a color in the middle (for example 'yellow') to create a distinction.

A [`TwoSlopeNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html) can pinpoint an exact value for the center.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9],
              [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0],
              [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3],
              [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0],
              [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6]])
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['#ff3d3d', 'yellow', '#74ff52'])
norm = matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=2.3, vmin=a.min(), vmax=a.max())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = ax.imshow(a, interpolation='none', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
plt.colorbar(img, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

At the left an example with yellow as central color, in the center with white and at the right without setting an explicit central color.

[image: resulting plot]

PS: If the central value wouldn't be between the minimum and the maximum, the whole image would either be reds or greens. In that case you could create the norm as:

```py
bounds = sorted([2.3,  a.min(), a.max()])
norm = matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=bounds[1], vmin=bounds[0], vmax=bounds[2])
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you a lot! Just one minor thing: i tried to use a different array of data, same number of rows and only different values, but i got the following error: vmin, vcenter, and vmax must be in ascending order. How can i sort vmin and vmax in order to avoid that?

Comment: Ok i'm sorry, i forgot a 0 and the middle value was bigger than vmax, my bad! Thank you a lot! This helped me immensely!

Comment: Indeed, i was going to happen how to handle when the value wasn't in between, but you already answered to that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution using the seaborn library. 
(Ideally have matplotlib 3.1.0 installed on your PC, as matplotlib 3.1.1 can causes problems when displaying the heatmap).

```py
import seaborn 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9],
              [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0],
              [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3],
              [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0],
              [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6]])

#b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
minVal = np.amin(a)
maxVal = np.amax(a)
diffs = abs(2.3 - a)

seaborn.heatmap(a, annot=True, linewidths=.5, square=True, vmin=np.amin(a), vmax=np.amax(a), cmap='RdYlGn')
plt.figure()
seaborn.heatmap(diffs, annot=True, linewidths=.5, square=True, vmin=np.amin(diffs), vmax=np.amax(diffs), cmap='Reds')
```

The first heatmap is your original 'a' matrix, which will look like this: 
[image: asdf]

The second heatmap represents the values a differs from 2.3, which will look like this:
[image: asdf]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! This is fine, but the problem is that i need to use MPL to generate heatmap, since later i will have to save the figure, which is a feature that only MPL has for now AFAIK

Comment: @JayK23  seaborn is just an interface on top of matplotlib. You can simply call `plt.savefig()` on a plot created by seaborn. You can also make changes and add extras to a seaborn plot using any matplotlib function. Therefore you usually grab the `ax` via `ax = sns.heatmap(...)`. Or provide an already created`ax` as a parameter to the seaborn function (`sns.heatmap(..., ax=ax)`).

Comment: I didn't know about this, since i'm just starting to dive deeper on MPL, but this opens to a bunch of new opportunities. I'm trying to do the same with seaborn too. Thank you a lot!