# Plot .npy array python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

After noise reduction, my array is this one:

```
[[1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 ..., 
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]]
```

And after trying to invert it with 1-array I still obtain a blue output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a description of how to use images under http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html.

Basically, matplotlib accepts normalized arrays, i.e. with values between 0 and 1. For your image data, this means that you have to divide it by 255.

An example would be

```py
normalized_image = np.load('testing.npy') / 255.

plt.imshow(normalized_image)
```

Or the following for an inverted image

```
plt.imshow(1 - normalized_image)
```

For a black and white image, you could use the solution given in [Plot a black-and-white binary map in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638826/plot-a-black-and-white-binary-map-in-matplotlib):

```py
plt.imshow(1 - normalized_image, cmap="Greys")
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the inverting of the image.

Comment: still obtaining a blue-ish image

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting a blue image because the default `colormap` is `jet`. One  of the end-members of `jet` is blue, hence you get a blue image. You can see the colormaps reference page [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

You can change the colormap of your image with the `cmap` kwarg. For example, for a monochrome image:

```
plt.imshow(image_array,cmap='Greys')
```

You may also need/want to set the limits of the image array so that the colours/shades correspond correctly with the colormap:

```
plt.imshow(image_array,cmap='Greys',vmin=0,vmax=1)
```