# How to save ax.plot information as pixel data?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

Given a simple example of code that **draws lines between given coordinates** with the use of ax.plot()

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_values = [0, 2, 4, 5]
y_values = [3, 1, 5, 2]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0,5)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)
ax.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.show()
```

[image: the pixel size, an interpolation needs to be made. But what is the best and easiest way?]

In order to do image processing, **I need the raw pixel data (b/w is sufficient) of that image, in a given pixel size, let it be `[MxN]`, given just the line endpoint coordinates** The data I am looking at would be an array with the dimensions of `[MxN]` just containing out of `0` and `1`.

Of cause there is interpolation needed, depending on the pixel size.
In my specific use case, I have very much and complex lines that are drawn with `ax.plot()`, so I wont be able to interpolate each line manually.

As I saw, there is [`ax.imshow()`,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638826/plot-a-black-and-white-binary-map-in-matplotlib) but this will not return a matrix/vector.
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the image as a jpg and then open it as an numpy array. You can check the shape to make sure it is to your liking.

```
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image

i = Image.open('name of your jpg.jpg')
array = np.asarray(i)
print(array.shape)
```

If you want to change the shape:

```
array.flatten().reshape(#M dim, #N dim)
```

Comment: Thanks! In order to import simple grayscale values, the command would be `i=Image.open('myjpg.jpy').convert('L')`, otherwise it is given in RBGA.