# Plot binary images with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to see a binary image with matplotlib like the image below:
[image]

I use this code to plot my images:

```
target_slope_rooftop_mask = target_slope_rooftop / target_slope_rooftop
target_aspect_rooftop_mask = target_aspect_rooftop / target_aspect_rooftop

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10))

target_slope_rooftop_mask.plot.imshow(
    cmap="Greys",
    ax=axs[0]
)
axs[0].set_title("Target rooftops based on slope")

target_aspect_rooftop_mask.plot.imshow(
    cmap="Greys",
    ax=axs[1]
)
axs[1].set_title("Target rooftops based on aspect")
```

But I see a gradient and not only black/white shapes.
[image]
How I can solve?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638826/plot-a-black-and-white-binary-map-in-matplotlib?

Comment: No, it is not usefull for me